# how to create a half bordered circle(only css, not js or even svg)?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am interested in creating something like the picture below. A counter box with a transparent background and a thin border, plus an icon in the bottom of that semi circle.

[image]

I made something like what I want, see below:

```
.chartBottom{
   width:0;
   height:0;
   border:60px solid #c45;
   border-bottom:60px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 60px;
 }
```

But the problem of this trick is that it can't have any transparent background. Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you use background image? you can create an image with photo shop or anything else and have circle+thumbs-up button in it and set it as a background of your container !

Comment: ummm, is it responsive? this circle and it's content should be resizable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this code instead of using border 60px and setting width and height to zero.use width and height and border 1px;

```
.chartBottom{
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    border:1px solid #c45;
    border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 60px
}
```

[here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/b3bvh90j/1/) is jsfiddle for you to see.

Comment: @bobsilon and here is a responsive version of this code : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/k0n2pv33/3/

Answer (score 1):

I think [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Thomas_S/vbf5cfrt/) should help you.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="chartBottom"></div>
    <div class="icon">Icon</div>
</div>
```

```css
.chartBottom {
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border:1px solid #c45;
    border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 60px;
}
.icon {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    top: -30px;
    left: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding: 3px;
    width: 126px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.circleDiv{

         width:120px;
         height:120px;
         border-right:1px solid white;
         border-top:1px solid white;
         border-left:1px solid white;
         border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
         border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u0493v0k/)

Comment: your solution is using `js` OP mentions only `CSS`

Comment: thanks, but i don't want to use js. i'm looking for css only tricks.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to add an absolute-positioned icon inside the relative-positioned container ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gtss907/5/)).

As for making it responsive, I recommend using media queries to adjust the values to keep the design tight (not included in fiddle).

http://jsfiddle.net/1gtss907/5/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='chartBottom'>
    <h4>56</h4>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
  </div>
  <p>Projects done this year</p>
</div>

body {
  background: #222;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding: 8em;
  text-align: center;
}

.chartBottom{
  border:1px solid #1abc9c;
  border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
}

p {
    color: #999; 
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    width: 100px;
}

i {
    color: #16a085;
    opacity: 0.75;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 45%;
}
```